# Processing list of items serially in order and returning ok when all is done (async -> sync)

Tags: javascript, q

I'm itching head with concept of promises and async procedures. I have ordered a list and want to call a function with every item, wait until first procedure with the first item is done, proceed to second, third and so on. And only after every item is processed I want continue the main process.

Below is the code that made it well with the main process. So returning Q.all(promises) resulted that first all promises were processed and then main process continued. But problem was, that items (navigation keys) were processed async while I need them in sync:

```
function processPages(that) {
  var navs = [];
  Object.keys(that.navigation).map(function(key) {
    navs.push({key: key, order: parseInt(that.navigation[key].index)});
  });
  var promises = navs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
  })
  .map(function(item) {
    return that.parsePage(item.key).then(function(page) {
      return page.sections.filter(function(section) {
        return section.type == 'normal';
      })
      .map(function(section) {
        collectStore(section, page, that);
      });
    });
  });
  return Q.all(promises);
}
```

Below is the code when I modified that items are processed in sync and right order, but now main process will be out of sync:

```
function processPages(that) {
  var navs = [];
  Object.keys(that.navigation).map(function(key) {
    navs.push({key: key, order: parseInt(that.navigation[key].index)});
  });
  var promises = navs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
  })
  .reduce(function(previous, item) {
    return previous.then(function () {
      return that.parsePage(item.key).then(function(page) {
        return page.sections.filter(function(section) {
          return section.type == 'normal';
        })
        .map(function(section) {
          collectStore(section, page, that);
        });
      });
    });
  }, Q());
  return Q.all(promises);
}
```

Does anyone know what is happening here and how to use promises right way in this case?

**Additional information**

processPages is called from init hook. If promise (Q.all) is not used, then page hook may fire before init hook is totally processed, which I cannot allow either. This is what I refer with the "main process".

```
module.exports =
{
  hooks: {
    "init": function() {
      var options = this.options.pluginsConfig['regexplace'] || {};
      options.substitutes = options.substitutes || {};
      // collects text replacement queries from plugin configuration
      options.substitutes.forEach(function (option) {
        patterns.push({re: new RegExp(option.pattern, option.flags || ''), 
                       sub: option.substitute,
                       decode: option.decode || false,
                       store: option.store || null,
                       unreset: option.unreset || false});
      });
      this.config.book.options.variables = this.config.book.options.variables || {};
      processPages(this);
    },
    "page": function(page) {
      var that = this;
      // process all normal sections in page
      page.sections.filter(function(section) {
        return section.type == 'normal';
      })
      .map(function(section) {
        collectStore(section, page, that, true);
      });
      return page;
    }
  }
};
```

Code is part of the GitBook plugin code.

Comment: *but now main process will be out of sync* does not describe anything but what you think it means. If you want things processed serially then do not use `promises` process them in a procedural loop.

Comment: Well, this is not entirely true... we should all probably take a look at this article [http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was as simple as changing:

```
processPages(this);
```

to

```
return processPages(this);
```

on init hook.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the runnable examples (from Chrome's dev console) from the [Understanding JavaScript Promise with Examples](http://kctang.github.io/blog/2015/05/09/understanding-javascript-promise-with-examples-no-more-callback-hell/), especially the "chaining" example.

Based on your description of *"...I have ordered a list and want to call a function with **every item**, wait until first procedure with the first item is done, proceed to second, third and so on. And only after every item is processed I want continue the **main process**."*,

From algorithm point of view, you should be "chaining" multiple promises together:

- create a Promise for every item. When an item is done, call resolve() so that then() will execute (next item in chain).
- put the "main process" as the last item in the chain.

Recommend you test/learn promises' execution flow with simple example before applying it in your problem - makes it easier to understand.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some ideas for tests. I already miss old times without too big promises.